# View Controller Button Connection Swift

Tags: swift

My I made multiple connections to my view controller from a button and now it doesn't work. I dragged the connection from the button to the view controller code. It created the button link on the view controller. I messed up a few times and had to re do it. Now its giving me an error that there are too many links. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you delete a connection in the code you need to make sure you delete it in story board.